# 3D pie Chart in Android

Tags: android, pie-chart

I want to make a 3D pie chart using openGL for android app any one can help me with it?
i have extended the `GLSurfaceView` class and the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` interface, but iam not sure how can i make the vertices for the pie chart to draw a cylinder.
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple:
    double ycount=45.0,ncount=0=35.0,zcount=20.0;
    WebView w1;
        w1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webpiechart);
                w1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        w1.loadUrl("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=400x150&chl=YES|NO|NOT_PARTICIPATED&chd=t:"+ycount+","+ncount+","+zcount);

Note: you require internet permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```